# Почему php потребляет разное количество памяти

Tags: php

Почему php при использовании одного и того же скрипта потребляет разное количество памяти?

Comment: оптимизация и кеширование

Comment: Уточню вопрос. Функция memory_get_usage() дает постоянно разный результат с одинаковым кодом

Comment: память тратится в основном не на код а на переменные. одна копия запущена пользователем "ab", и на хранение его имени тратится 2 байта плюс накладные расхды. А для пользователя "Череззаборногузадирищенский" придется потратить уже 54 байта (если это utf-8). А если вы там целые большие массивы передаете по значению (что обычно и делают) то вообще про свободную память можете забыть